# It is possible to use Google Cloud Messaging (GCM push notifications) to achieve these needs?

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

We have a system that generates android apps automatically. The users enter in our website and login in their accounts and the users make a description of wich functionalities want and our system automatically generates the signed android apk and publishes on market.

The apps are published on the market with our developer account, not with the user account.

Such users would need PUSH notifications, for example, through GCM, to their applications. Therefore, we need to know if there is any way to automate the process so that users only have to enter on our website their google accounts and the message they want to send their applications, and our system must automatically send the messages to the phones that uses the user applications.

You have to remember and highlight the following factors:

- Applications are published in the market under our developer account.
- Users who have created their apps through our system have their own google accounts (not developer accounts) and want to send their messages from their accounts of Google and to its applications only, not those of others users and not using our google developer account.
- The whole process should be automatic and transparent to the user, since they should only provide these data, their google account, the message they want to send, and the app that must receive the message.
  Would it be possible to do this by GCM?

There is a GCM API with which to communicate to perform all these steps automatically?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you could, but the user must register in GoogleApis to have their own SENDER_ID, then you should make a webservice in which you associate each user to their SENDER_ID and provide them an interface that only send notificatios using their SENDER_ID, however you should have a strong enough server to achieve this since Big Data could be an issue because you must also store the device_ids associated with each of your clients application, also you would be getting registration and unregistration intents from each application installed.

Answer (score 0):

I have used Both Server Side (Grails) & Client Side (Titanium) to send notifications to the android device. So, I will be explaining you both one by one. But before that you need to add ADT plugin in to your Grails framework.check out http://tinyurl.com/chfthpe